# When I declare a variable as an Interface, and then assign a concrete type to it, where is the declaration type saved?

Tags: c#, .net, types, interface

In the code below, the type object pointer for both objects point to the type List of integers.

```
IEnumerable<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
```

Where is the type, in which list1 was declared (IEnumerable), stored in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it answers your question or not, but it's stored in the `.locals` section of the IL.

```
.maxstack 1
.entrypoint
.locals init (
    [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> list1,
    [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32> list2
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
IL_000c: stloc.1
IL_000d: ret
```

That is not exactly "runtime" though. At runtime the JIT will most likely turn this into raw pointer operations, so your answer is probably "nowhere". Alternatively, because it's only important that the *compiler* knows what type the variable has at compile time, the answer is "in your source code".

Comment: When the IL is jitted. In the stack, we have a pointer to the object (which does not hold any type information) and the object itself in the heap (which holds type information in type object pointer, and it is List)

So how are list1 and list 2 are distinguished? Maybe the "declaration" type is compile-time only?

Comment: What do you mean by distinguished? The pointers in `list1` and `list2` are different, they already point to different interfaces of different objects. There is no need to further distinguish anything.

Comment: By distinguish I mean, how does the CLR know list1 is IEnumerable and list2 is List. Where is this information stored?

Comment: @Ivak - That information isn't stored anywhere, only the C# compiler needs to know the declaration type.

Comment: Before JIT runs, it's written in the IL, in a static form. After the JIT runs, it's not stored anywhere because it's not needed. You don't need to know what type you are calling as long as the JIT has prepared the pointer for you to call. You just push the parameters to stack and call the prepared pointer.

Comment: @Lee, GSerg - Thank you, this is what I was looking for